# Values are not initialized in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have a form where i set default value of each input. Initial values are set before with `useEffect`:

```js
  const [text, setText] = useState({ note: "", gender: "" });
  useEffect(() => {
    setText({
      note: "2",
      gender: "demo"
    });
  }, []);
```

After that the i set default value of the form in this way:

```js
<Form
      initialValues={{ note: text.note, gender: text.gender }} //default values
      {...layout}
      form={form}
      name="control-hooks"
      onFinish={onFinish}
    >
```

The issue is that i can get the values inside inputs, probably they don't manage to be set as default values. How to solve this?

link to my app: https://codesandbox.io/s/form-methods-ant-design-demo-kbwgk

Answer (score 3):

You should set the inside `useState`:

`useState({ note: "2", gender: "demo" })`

If you set the inside useEffect the form would have already been initialised with the empty values from useState

https://codesandbox.io/s/form-methods-ant-design-demo-whq5v

Answer (score 0):

## Set defaults in initialization

You are making an extra render by using useEffect. Just put defaults in the `useState` function.

```
const [text, setText] = useState({ note: "2", gender: "demo" });
```

## Make sure changes are detected

Your values should be immutable so changes can be detected.
I would recommend spreading the values when using them so they appear as a new object.

```
<Form
  initialValues={{...text}}
  {...layout}
  form={form}
  name="control-hooks"
  onFinish={onFinish}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `initialValues` on **first render**, with `useEffect` you set it **on the second render** (that's how `useEffect` works, there is enough material on it across the site).

```
<Form initialValues={{ note: "2", gender: "demo" }} />;
```

Comment: but which will be the solution if i can't set directly `initialValues={{ note: "2", gender: "demo" }}`, but  i want in this way `initialValues={{ note: text.note, gender: text.gender }}`. What do you think?

Comment: You asked how to initialize a form, that's the answer. If something else works for its good

Answer (score -1):

solved:  `form.setFieldsValue({note: text.note, gender: text.gender})`

Comment: It is a dynamic fieldset and no real initialization (should happen once on the component mount), the right way is mentioned in the docs using `Form.create`

Comment: @DennisVash, i found this on antd site: `You cannot set value for each form control via value or defaultValue prop, you should set default value with initialValues of Form. Note that initialValues cannot be updated by setState dynamiclly, you should use setFieldsValue in that situation.`

Comment: See my answer, as for `v4`, `initialValues` is for first render

Comment: @DennisVash, could you show please, how to use `Form.create`?

Comment: @DennisVash, i found in documentation that i can use this: `React.useEffect(() => {
    form.setFieldsValue({
      username: 'Bamboo',
    });
  }, []);`, but with useEffect, the initial value does not appear. Also i found this:  `Since Form.create() is removed, origin onFieldsChange or other methods moved to Form, and control by fields. ref example`